# AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'signaltonoise'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, attributeerror

I'm using scipy signaltonoise function below is the code but it returns an error. I searched regarding this in github too but couldn't find it. Can you please help.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
import os
import csv
from scipy import stats 
from PIL import Image
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from multiprocessing import Pool
from skimage.feature import local_binary_pattern # Local Binary Pattern function
from scipy.stats import itemfreq # To calculate a normalized histogram
import scipy.stats as sp
from skimage.feature import hog
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label
from scipy import signal as sg




def calc_snr(img):
    snr = stats.signaltonoise(img, axis=None)
    return snr


 snr = calc_snr(img)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`scipy.stats.signaltonoise()` was [deprecated in scipy 0.16.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.16.0.html#deprecated-features) and removed in 1.0.0. If you need to use the function without downgrading scipy, you can see the original code from the function before it was removed on github [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L1963), and reproduced below:

```
import numpy as np
def signaltonoise(a, axis=0, ddof=0):
    a = np.asanyarray(a)
    m = a.mean(axis)
    sd = a.std(axis=axis, ddof=ddof)
    return np.where(sd == 0, 0, m/sd)
```